# Best way to provide formatting to news articles stored in databases

Tags: database, database-design, web

I am working on a news web page and I will like to know what are the best practices for storing the news articles into the database. The problem is that if I store the news articles in pure text I lose the ability to insert links or provide any HTML formatting to the news's body when I show them on the page. On the other side, I've seen that storing it already formatted in HTML or XML or any other formatting language could couple the database info to an HTML environment.

So, is there any way to accomplish this? I've been thinking in store the news both ways into the database. Is there any better approach to solve this problem?

I am using php (Symfony2 being more specific) and if the markup language are the way to do this, which one do you recommend?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most systems that I have developed / worked on have stored both the marked up content and the original base content. The primary reason to store the original base content is that the layout (Css, styles, Html design, etc.) is typically frequent to change.

It can add significant overhead to a migration / upgrade project when upgrading the website design and then having to write custom parsers to strip out the markup.

Comment: Ok, is more or less as I supposed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use ckEditor for your link markup or HTML like
 --- namelink,  www.example.com ---
Then your php format it.